What happen in calculate $ (\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{J}) (\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{J} - 1) $?
If I use $ \boldsymbol{J} = \boldsymbol{L} + \boldsymbol{S} = \boldsymbol{L} + \frac{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}{2} $, then
\begin{align*}
 (\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{J}) (\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{J} - 1) & = (\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{L} + \frac{3}{2}) (\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{L} + \frac{3}{2} - 1) \\
 & = (\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{L})^{2} + 2 \boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{L} + \frac{3}{4} \\
 & = L^{2} + \boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{L} + \frac{3}{4} \\
 & = L^{2} + 2 \boldsymbol{S} \cdot \boldsymbol{L} + S^{2} \\
 & = (\boldsymbol{L} + \boldsymbol{S})^{2} \\
 & = J^{2}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
 (\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{L})^{2} = L^{2} + i\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot (\boldsymbol{L} \times \boldsymbol{L}) = L^{2} - \boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{L} 
\end{align*}
but if I use
\begin{align*}
 (\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{J})^{2} = J^{2} - \boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{J} 
\end{align*}
then I have
\begin{align*}
 (\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{J}) (\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{J} - 1) & = (\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{J})^{2} - \boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{J} \\
 & = J^{2} - 2\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{J} \\
 & \neq J^{2}
\end{align*}
So which equation is right, and what wrong with another equation?
Thanks by LiZ.

Your first expression is correct, the second one is wrong. It is true that
$$
(\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{L})^2=L^2-\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{L} \ ,
$$
but you cannot generalize this to $\vec{J}$:
$$
(\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{J})^2\neq J^2-\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{J} \ ,
$$
because $\vec{S}=\vec{\sigma}/2$ and $[\sigma_i,\sigma_j]=2i\epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k\neq0$, so $
(\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{J})^2\neq\sigma_i\sigma_kJ_iJ_k$.

Thank you. It is I who take it for granted think that if the same index of vector commute with Pauli matrix is ok.

Your calculations are inconsistent because you need to rather assume in a simultaneous eigenspace of $J^2,S^2,L^2$ (which commute):
$$
J^2 =j(j+1) \quad L^2=l(l+1) \quad S^2 = s(s+1)
$$
From there, you can compute spin orbit coupling:
$$
L\cdot S = \frac12(J^2-L^2-S^2) = \frac12[j(j+1)-l(l+1)-s(s+1)]
$$
as well as:
$$
S\cdot J = S^2+S\cdot J = \frac12[j(j+1)-l(l+1)+s(s+1)]
$$
so your quantity is (both you results were wrong):
$$
(\sigma\cdot J)[(\sigma\cdot J)-1] = [j(j+1)-l(l+1)+s(s+1)][j(j+1)-l(l+1)+s(s+1)-1]
$$
